# Simple code to create welcome panel

Tags: html, css

I want to create a quick panel for some kind of menu in welcome page. This is back office panel I'm talking about. Maybe what I want to create is something like Windows 8 metro tile, but much, much more simple.

My experimental code so far is:

```
<span class="panel">a</span>
<span class="panel">b</span>
<span class="panel">c</span>
<span class="panel">d</span>
<span class="panel">e</span>
<span class="panel">f</span>
<span class="panel">g</span>
<span class="panel">h</span>
<span class="panel">i</span>
<span class="panel">j</span>
<span class="panel">k</span>
<span class="panel">l</span>
```

and my CSS is:

```
.panel  { 
   width: 300px; 
   height: 300px; 
   background-color: #999; 
   margin: 20px; 
   position:relative; 
}
```

What I've envisioning I would have by this experimental code is:

- 12 gray panel 300x300px, each has one letter inside it,
- each separated by 40px from each other,
- autoflow (means they will forms to the right next to each other like words, like how you see "tiled" view for files and folder on windows explorer. And if I resize the window, the panel will reflow to the bottom).

but the problem is I got small boxes surrounding the letter exactly as the size of the letter instead, not 300x300px. But they do forms to the right of each other (reflow). If I change the spans to divs, then it will produce 300x300px boxes, but the boxes will forms vertically. How to solve this dilemma? Thanks.

Comment: You mean like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/4Lxuk/)? Height and Width get applied only on block/inline-block elements. Spans are by nature inline elements.

Comment: @Harry right! Oh I see what you mean. Thanks a bunch! You should make your comment an answer dude! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<span>` tags are by default `inline` elements and hence the `height` and `width` properties will not apply on them. On the other hand, the `<div>` tags are by default `block` elements, so when you add multiple `div`s they take 100% of available width and get assigned one below the other.

To solve this, you need to set the `display` as `inline-block`. As the value name indicates, it is a hybrid of `inline` and `block`. `block` because you can assign them a `height` and a `width`. `inline` because they can all be placed on the same line as long as the available width permits. In case, the end is reached, the following element is wrapped around to the next line.

```
.panel {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: #999;
    margin: 20px;
    position:relative;
    display: inline-block; /* to set multiple blocks on same line */
    line-height: 100px; /* vertical center because the box has only one alphabet */
    text-align: center; /* horizontal center */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/4Lxuk/) | [**Display Property - MDN Spec**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

Comment: Thanks! And thanks too for making it centered vertically and horizontally!